# Using Chrome Inspect Element For Tracking Down Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

These are the errors in my console,

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jwplayer(1).js:1
    GET file:///Users/Desktop/home/homes_files/84820220.html net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND homes_files/84820220.html:1
    GET file:///Users/Desktop/home/homes_files/bLBBWlYJp_w.html net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND homes_files/bLBBWlYJp_w.html:1
    GET file:///Users/Desktop/home/homes_files/bLBBWlYJp_w(1).html net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND homes_files/bLBBWlYJp_w(1).html:1
    GET file:///Users/Desktop/home/homes_files/getSegment.html net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND homes_files/getSegment.html:1
    GET file:///Users/Desktop/home/homes_files/index.a92414725f76870a42ebbab80c488823.html net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND homes_files/index.a92414725f76870a42ebbab80c488823.html:1
    GET file:///Users/Desktop/home/homes_files/images/overlay.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin '' in a call to 'postMessage'. st.aa03925d5a5cf99815b298eaa597d946.js:1
    broadcastSendMessage st.aa03925d5a5cf99815b298eaa597d946.js:1
    (anonymous function) st.aa03925d5a5cf99815b298eaa597d946.js:1
    (anonymous function) st.aa03925d5a5cf99815b298eaa597d946.js:1
    GET file:///Users/Desktop/home/images/sep-02.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
```

My questions is, 
If I want to track down the origin of these errors what is the rule of them?

For example,

`GET file:///Users/Desktop/home/homes_files/images/overlay.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2`

I know the error here is the file path should actually be

```
Users/Desktop/home/images/overlay.png
```

Now the file referenced in my example is,

```
jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
```

But no where in that file does it mention the incorrect file path for me to change. How can i track errors like this using the console?

Also I am using Chrome Devtools Autosave, so if there is a way to do this without ever leaving the console that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually an error caught in jQuery is actually a problem upstream of that. You'll have to use a process of elimination to narrow things down.

Comment: I understand that, But is there a way to track down where that incorrect file path is coming from? I have used find in every file and can't seem to find anywhere that it is referenced.

Comment: I'd focus on `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jwplayer(1).js:1` and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin '' in a call to 'postMessage'. st.aa03925d5a5cf99815b298eaa597d946.js:1`